# How do I make Ace editor resize its height accordingly to the number of rows?

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide, ace-editor

What do I do to configure Ace to have its height so that all lines will be always visible, rather than having a vertical scrollbar?

Basically, the equivalent of:

```
document.querySelector("textarea").oninput = function(){
    this.rows = this.value.split(/\n/g).length;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/obobjrf5/

How do I do that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `maxLines` option `editor.setOption("maxLines", 1000)`.